# Mac Mini does not recognize USB Keyboard at start up

Tags: keyboard, usb, mac-mini

I am using a Quickfire Stealth mechanical USB Keyboard for my Mac Mini. I am having an issue that each time I boot the computer, I have to plug it out from the USB port and plug it back in for the Mac Mini to recognize it.

Anyone has an idea what could be the cause for this weird behavior?

Comment: Mid 2010, Processor  2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, Memory  8 GB 1067 MHz DDR3, Graphics  NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB, Software  OS X 10.9